# Close FFMPEG if connection with ipcam lost

Tags: batch-file, ffmpeg, youtube, rtsp, ip-camera

this is my scrit that transmit a live camera rtsp stream to youtube rtmp stream.

The Script before start verify if connection with camera is alive.

The problem is during the process, if network connection lost ffmpeg remain in locked state.

It's possibile to close ffmpeg or restart task if connection with camera lost?

```
:LOOP
timeout /t 10
ping 192.168.1.11
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 goto exit
IF ERRORLEVEL 0 goto START
:START

ffmpeg  -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://192.168.1.11:10554/tcp/av0_0 -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -t 12:00:00 -pix_fmt + -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/(secret code)

goto LOOP
```

Comment: You'll need another batch to check status or detach ffmpeg from the current batch with `start ""  ffmpeg ....`

Answer (score 1):

This is the solution:

CHECK Task run every minutes
If there is a problem with the connetection of camera, the process kill all  istance off ffmpeg and restart the primary task.

```
@echo off
set "host=192.168.1.11"

ping -n 1 "%host%" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
    echo Success.
) else (
echo Camera offline il %date% alle ore %time% >>C:\Users\Gianluca\Desktop\script\log.txt
WMIC PROCESS WHERE "COMMANDLINE LIKE '%%ffmpeg%%'" call terminate
schtasks /Run /TN "webcam"

)
```

The primary task check the  connetection of camera and if connection lost, close the windows.

```
:LOOP
set "host=192.168.1.11"

ping -n 1 "%host%" | findstr /r /c:"[0-9] *ms"

if %errorlevel% == 0 (
   goto START
) else (

exit

)
pause


:START

ffmpeg  -f lavfi -i anullsrc -rtsp_transport tcp -i rtsp://%host%:10554/tcp/av0_0 -tune zerolatency -vcodec libx264 -t 12:00:00 -pix_fmt + -c:v copy -c:a aac -strict experimental -f flv rtmp://a.rtmp.youtube.com/live2/code

goto LOOP
```

Comment: Functional but ugly solution.

Answer (score 0):

I found that ffmpeg compiled with cygwin will not be hung and will exit after timeout.

https://cygwin.com/packages/summary/ffmpeg.html